# Handling six years of gap in resume

Tags: resume, employment-gaps

I have done a Bachelor of Engineering in IT in 2008, but because of the recession I didn't get a job after graduating. After that, I had to live at home for family reasons and tried for a government job. Because of what has happened it has never allowed me to get a grip on my career. Due to this I now have a  six year gap & want to get a job it IT. During this gap I kept myself in touch with IT field but I do not have formal guidance from anyone so somewhere along the line. Because of this I have lost confidence & I can't decide how to overcome this.

Comment: It's still a résumé gap, whether or not it's a gap between jobs or a gap between education and first job.

Comment: Start doing open-source coding or similar - get your confidence back up, and list your contributions on your resume - maybe even take a couple classes to learn new features or go for a masters

Answer (score 8):

You have received a diploma in 2008 and are now back searching for a job. There are some issues you will need to address, and we will tackle them one by one.

## 1. It has been a while since you practiced IT. Are you still any good at it?

Although you cannot add formal 'job experience', you should describe what you mean by 'I kept in touch'. Did you contribute to any open-source projects? Did you do some projects on the side?

## 2. Why did you not get a job? What is wrong with you?

The goal here is to show this is due to external factors. Maybe your family suffered a major drama? Maybe you got married very young, got a kid and decided to stay home to take care of it. Anyway, the exact reason is not important. What is important is: "The reasons are very clear, and they have been resolved."

Make it out to be a conscientious choice, not a necessity because you are *unemployable*.

Show that the reasons for not getting a job are now in the past. You are ready to get a job and go for it, with the same enthusiasm as a young graduate!

## 3. You have no job experience. You have an entry-level profile.

Try to show that you are looking for entry-level positions with an entry-level salary. You offer the same value-for-money as other young graduates. Maybe even more value, as you have more life experience.

Comment: +1 - What is important is: "The reasons are very clear, and they have been resolved."

Answer (score 2):

As somoene who recently had to deal with a three-year gap in employment after graduation, here's the best advice I can offer.

**Be Honest**

You had a hard time getting a job after college.  It happens. You put your best foot forward, but sometimes you can't afford to go to all the interviews you'd like, or you have to take part-time jobs to pay the bills and can't get your desired career started, or you've just had terrible luck.  It happens.  Be honest and show them the effort you *did* make to get work.  They will be more impressed with your honesty and your effort if you put it forward yourself.

**Focus On Your Career**

That being said, six years IS a huge gap to fill, and if you haven't been focusing on your career for those years, you should start now.  Skills, especially technical skills like IT ability, can deteriorate over time, and require re-learning.  If you've been taking classes, or even self-studying, emphasize this as much as possible.  Find ways to fill in that empty time with anything you can, even if it seems insignificant to you ("I was practicing and studying my coding at home while seeking work" helps).

**Make Your Talents Marketable**

And when I say you should start now, I mean right now, start brushing up on your core talents.  Good IT positions will require them, and good IT interviewers will test them right at the gate.  This cannot be emphasized enough - even just picking up some of your old textbooks from college and going over them again will help you here.  The important thing is to keep enough knowledge retained so that, on the day of your interview, you can show them you know exactly what you're doing.

**Addendum**

All of that being said, parasietje is correct - you are going to be looking for an entry-level position, and you should aim accordingly.  Be realistic about what you can do, but don't sell yourself short either.  If you DO still have your college-level IT skills and can brush them up appropriately, with some effort, you can find yourself a good position.

Answer (score -2):

Try to come up with excuses that sound plausible, but can't be verified.  I've told employers that (well, this was true, but you get the idea) I visited my family out of state for extended amounts of time to help out.  Then I took some vacations too.  Being unemployed, I didn't have to worry about taking time off work.  (One recruiter told me I should've looked for work first, THEN did the vacations, but, whatever.)  Six years is a long time, but if you're young, no better time to start then now.

Comment: No matter what the idealists in the ivory towers say, this, in practice, is the best idea.