# How to explain a gap in my resumé (tried to change job)

Tags: resume

I worked in IT (software engineer) and, fed up with this job, decided to try and change to another career. I went back to study (woodworking) but it didn't work out in the end. I am now considering going back to IT, since it pays the bills. But how to explain the gap in my resumé without sounding like I don't like IT and raising all kinds of red flags ?

Best regards,

PS : I'm French

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling six years of gap in resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19815/handling-six-years-of-gap-in-resume)

Comment: There are lots and lots of employment gap questions with answers, too many to list, so voted to close

Answer (score 4):

"I decided to switch from IT to woodworking, but it wouldn't work out".

And of course you add that you were always very successful as a software engineer, but you just didn't have the talent for woodworking, and it would be better to do something that you are really good at.

"IT pays the bills" is probably not a good thing to say. Although I had a colleague once who played in a reasonably successful professional rock band of four, and he said it is very, very hard for four people to make the same money as a band that they can make in four good jobs.

Comment: Surely you mean: "... but it woodn't work out" :D

Answer (score 3):

Say that you were studying. I don't see why that would raise a red flag. It makes no difference if you studied joinery or philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

> I've decided to spend more time on my hobby projects. I've had money from my previous job (IT pays well), but not enough time, so I took some time off.

If they're more interested, then you can go on how CNC routers/lathes work in general, and what special properties wood has, and how important it was to learn a bit more about woodworking for your super-special CNC machine, and you're done.

A lot of IT companies encourage having hobbies or pet projects (good for morale, could be turned into a product, also good to have people with various skills). Since computers can be found everywhere, it's easy to find something IT related in them.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than explain the break as an attempt at a career change (which might bring up questions about why the OP wanted to change careers, and why they changed back) I'd frame it more that the OP took a sabbatical - a planed, mid career break to recharge and exercise some other parts of their person - with the expectation that they'd always return to IT.